# Как в idea GOland указать с какими параметрами командной строки запускать проект

Tags: golang, goland

Как в idea GOland указать с какими параметрами командной строки запускать проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

открыть настройки запуска вашего приложения, изменить параметры аргументов программы.

например, запустить вашу программу, Goland примет некую конфигурацию. Нажать "Edit configurations..." -> выбрать вашу -> сохранить. см фото

p.s. если хотите менять на постоянной основе, то можно изменить шаблон "Go Build", но это затронет все-все-все запуски.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]